# How would I draw a state transition diagram to satisfy this regular expression?

Tags: regular-expressions

I somewhat understand finite state machines in concept however am unsure how I would apply it in this example. The question is

Draw the transition diagram of a finite state recogniser which accepts precisely those strings which satisfy the regular expression :

$c(((ab) \cup(bc))a)^*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of problems are puzzles of sorts. The first thing I would do is to consider what strings are contained in your regular expression. Since the star operator allows repetition of *zero* or more of the symbols in its argument, we have that $c$ is an acceptable string.

Also, the parantheses inside the star operator $((ab)\cup(bc))a$ gives you the substrings $aba$ and $bca$, and since any string has to start with a $c$, both $caba$ and $cbca$ are acceptable strings.

Because of the star operator, in fact any repetition of $aba$ or $bca$ after the $c$ will be an acceptable string, e.g.

$$cabaaba$$
$$cbcaaba$$
$$cababcabcaaba$$
etc.

So I need a machine that ends up in an accepting state when it is given a $c$ as input, and from here, any succession of the strings $aba$ and $bca$ should end back up in the accepting state. Any other input should be trashed.

In my drawing below, the middle state (marked "S") is the starting state (which I signify by the arrow leading into it from nowhere), and the bottom middle state (marked "A") is the accepting state. I use the top state for trash, i.e. whenever I come across a symbol I don't like, I redirect the machine to the trash state. Once you are in the trash state, you can never go back. The trash state cannot be escaped.

[image]

Comment: Very helpful answer. Thank you!